# Format for specifying field value in updateRecord LDS call for mutiselect picklist in LWC js

Tags: lightning-web-components, lds, updaterecord

I'm referring to the document to make use of out of box  import { updateRecord, } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'; It is straight forward to understand how to pass field values from the given example in the document for updateRecord.   [updateRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record)

```
 const fields = {};
        fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.contactId;
        fields[FIRSTNAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.template.querySelector("[data-field='FirstName']").value;
        fields[LASTNAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.template.querySelector("[data-field='LastName']").value;

        const recordInput = { fields };

        updateRecord(recordInput)
            .then(() => {
```

Example is for single values. My question is if one of the field is a multi select picklist, say states, how do I pass that value ( even hard coded ) to the field name in LWC js. I tried many combinations

1. `fname__c:"NY;CT;NJ"`
2. `fname__c:["NY","CT","NJ"]`

nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_update_record), The updateRecord uses ui-api and accept the [recordInput](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_requests_record_input.htm) as parameter.

One of the properties of **recordInput** is fields. If you have a multiselect picklist, you can pass the value like this:-

> MultiPicklist—JSON String (for example, Dog;Cat;Fish).

I have tried it in workbench and it worked:-

[image]

Coming to LWC, You can pass multiselect value as:-

```
fields[MULTISELECT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = "value1;Value2;value3";
```

Also, do not forget to import the multiselect field first as follow:-

```
import MULTISELECT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/ObjectApiName.FieldApiName';
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the mistake I did. Even though the document says fields[FIRSTNAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] ="myvalueforthisfield";    it will also work if we write this line like this  fields['FirstName'].value = "myvalueforthisfield";   that is without actually importing the field .   But that approach will fail for multi value fields.   So as you said IMPORT FIELD and bind it the documented way  fields[MULTISELECT_FIELD.fieldApiName]   and pass the values as semicolon separated string.